# Why does OAuth return "expires in"

Tags: oauth

I noticed that OAuth 2 in its spec recommends the use of a property `expires_in` that defines how long the access code is valid.

This seems backwards to me, as the API still needs to calculate the time at which this expires to save it in the database, and the receiver needs to do the same. It seems much more sane to pass the expiry time as a standardised UNIX timestamp, which both the API and the application can save in their db to check for expiry times.

Comment: Maybe because server and device time are not always in sync? Even if you keep timezones in mind it's not unusual to have a time difference of a few seconds or even minutes, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody seems to have an answer to this I'll add my assumption as an answer:

Server and device times will not always match. Which is why a duration is the more logical way to go.

Consider a user disabling time-syncing with servers and manually setting his/her time 1 week in the past. The tokens received from oAuth servers don't take this into account, they just set an expiry date and send a timestamp to the device assuming the device's clock is in sync AND it will convert the timestamp to the correct device timezone.

By sending a duration these "misunderstandings" can be bypassed.